# How do I avoid Invalid Cell Reference when =OFFSET is referring to a cell filled by =TEXTSPLIT

Tags: excel, excel-formula, split, reference, offset

I have an Excel file with a template page that uses the TEXTSPLIT function as follows.

```
=TEXTSPLIT(A3,";",,FALSE,,)
```

This is meant to take data from a CSV file and split it out in columns B to F. I want to take the data in column C for the rolling average using:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C4,0,0,-10,0)
```

however when I try to apply this I am getting an Invalid Cell Reference Error, if I click on the cell I am trying to reference

To start the process I take the formulas in my template where column B is filled down with =TEXTSPLIT for each row that the CSV file makes automatically along with my averaging calculations and fill across worksheets to the imported CSV data.

I have tried typing in the data into my Template sheet but I still get the same reference error for the rolling average.

Some example data, had to split it up weird sorry:

```
-2E-5;0;-0.0060090136;-0.0002997003;0


-1.98E-5;-0.0040444895;0.0040060091;-0.0002997003;-0.00010111224


-1.94E-5;-0.0040444895;-0.0020030045;-0.0002997003;0


-1.9E-5;0.0040444895;-0.0040060091;-0.0002997003;-0.00020222447


-1.88E-5;-0.0040444895;0.0020030045;0;-0.00040444895
```

The first value is an initial time stamp, then there are 4 channels of saved data. The only data I'm interested in, what I'm trying to extract is from the first channel.

Comment: can you provide some test examples of the original text and desired output for those test entries?  Something we can copy paste.

Comment: It was too long to copy and paste into a comment, please see the edit to my post. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the average of the first channel:

```
=AVERAGE(BYROW(A1:A5,LAMBDA(r,--CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(r,";"),2))))
```

That splits the values on the `;` and then chooses the second column and average the returned array.

[image]

Comment: that seems to work, for my understanding the formula you're using here splits the string of data and specifies interest in the second column of data. It does this using a custom Lambda function which does the actual text split, then uses choosecolumn to pull that data. It passes this data on a row-by-row basis using byrow to get those values and pass them to the average function yes?

Comment: It goes row by row, splits the data on the `;` then takes the second column of the result.  This loop happens row by row till the end creating an array of numbers from the second column.  That array is then passed to the average.

Comment: Here is another alternative, without using `LAMBDA()` not posting it as an answer, `=AVERAGE(TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(A1:A5,";",1),";")+0)` if it has to be the second column as always then this will also work.

Comment: after a security update which required some of my Windows settings to be reset the Lambda function is no longer functioning. The filled cells had "_xlfn. and _xlpm." behind some of the functions and #NAME? in the cells. When I tried to copy in the formula again I got an error pointing to the "r" in the Lambda function as the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is just a problem with your OFFSET formula, the 5th argument `width` is asking how many columns do you want to include, but you've got a 0 there. Try with a 1 instead:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C4,0,0,-10,1)
```

Edit: the below will ensure that you don't refer to nonexistent rows:

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(C3,0,0,-MIN(ROW(C3),10),1))
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested and changed the 0 to a 1 in my offset formula. Upon doing so I started getting a DIV/0 error instead.  I tried changing the offset argument to have a positive height of both 10 and 1 both of which still have the division error. 

Weirdly I still get the reference error for rows 3 to 9, my data starts on row 3

Comment: DIV/0 would indicate that all of the cells from your OFFSET formula are blank or 0. If you get the REF error up to row 9, but not from row 10, that would indicate you still have -10 in your OFFSET formula. I've updated the answer to avoid referring to non-existent rows.